# using mongoDB with heroku on production

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, backend, heroku-api

I'm using nodejs as a backend, an mongoDB as a database.
I have free atlas on mongodb and a free dyno on heroku for developing.

I'll finish developig my App soon and I'll have to buy production plans of both heroku and mongoDB so,
MY QUESTION is, is there a mongoDB that I can install on heroku and use it along with my heroku app?? or do I have to buy an Atlas and connect it to heroku?

Comment: You have to use one of the add-ons.

Comment: which one? I only heard of MLab but heroku says it's discontinued.

Comment: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/ormongo appears to be one option.

Comment: You don't _have to_ use one of the add-ons. Any cloud-hosted server will do. If you want to upgrade to a paid Atlas database, upgrade to a paid Atlas database.